Как получать доход с приложения без Google Pay?
Не знаю, можно ли спрашивать это здесь, но рискну. Я разработал приложение в Android Studio на Java и хочу выложить его в Google Play. Основные юзеры будут российские пользователи. Но сейчас Google Pay, который предлагает маркет Google Play, недоступен для России. В моем приложении есть подписка, а также есть разовая покупка услуг. Подскажи, пожалуйста, как мне предоставить возможность купить услуги в приложении российскому пользователю? Могу ли я использовать что-то кроме Google Pay? Если могу, то не нарушает ли это законы Google Маркета? Если нарушает, то как их законно обойти, чтобы мое приложение не удалили? Как вообще сейчас живут российские разработчики? Большое спасибо за ответ.

В магазине Google Play нет законов, там политика.. Тематика сайта "Ответы на вопросы по программированию", а не как живут или где отдыхают.

Подключай appodeal, или любой другой аналог, и не парься. В данном случае это быстрее, и будет конверсия выше. Из минусов - приложение будет весить на 20 мегабайт больше.


Время инди разработчиков уже кончилось лет 5 назад, как минимум... Золотое время было лет 10 назад, тогда можно было выйти с приложением и реально заработать. Сейчас работают в основном крупные компании или слаженные группы разработчиков, уже имеющие раскрученные приложения. Без продвижения нереально что-то заработать, исключения конечно есть, но это лотерея шансы 1 на 100 тыс.
В Google Play монетизация для разработчиков из России сильно затруднена, там осталась единственная лазейка покупка внутри приложений через сторонние (не гугловские сервисы)
Если целевая аудитория российские пользователи, то прямая дорога в RuStore (не реклама!) - там есть полный цикл монетизации.
Идите на работать - там можно больше и быстрее заработать :)


Спасибо за ответ. Если вы знаете, уточните, пожалуйста, как именно работает обход. Допустим, если использовать сторонние сервисы (какие, если у вас есть информация), например, оплату через «ЮMoney», это не нарушает политику Google Play? Я вычитал законный обход. Пользователя перекидывает на сайт, где можно купить что-либо, но это не совсем мне подходит. В RuStore тоже заходить буду. У меня сейчас цель не заработок, я защищаю диссертацию в формате диплом как стартап)

Без понятия, насколько я понимаю это не противоречит правилам, вы же когда заказываете доставку в Яндексе или Сбермаркете оплачиваете мимо кассы Google и все работает. По сути это то же самое.

@Barmaley вы не путайте цифровые товары и физические товары или услуги.

А в чем они принципиально друг от друга отличаются? В любом более-менее вменяемом маркетплейсе можно купить и физический и цифровой товар неразличимо друг от друга: например книжку физическую или электронную - оплата не отличается вообще ничем. Слегка отличается логистика и то на уровне абстракции приложения - отличий нет.
